# Strange arangodb datafile size

Tags: arangodb

I am using arangodb 2.6.2 and one of the collection holds data for last 2 days. I am noticing strange datafiles collection where it is holding up to 4.7 gb. Alive size is 233 mb and dead size is 2.08mb. I have attached the screenshot. Could somebody explain what exactly happening.

[image]

Comment: can you run `curl --dump - http://localhost:8529/_api/collection/raw/figures` and have a look at the shapes information? This will most probably reveal the used size.

Comment: Getting connection reset by peer. But it is surely having 15 million shapes count.

Comment: maybe you need to add authentication parameters? I.e. `curl --dump - http://localhost:8529/_api/collection/_users/figures` [gives me the figures for the system collection _users](https://docs.arangodb.com/HttpCollection/Getting.html#return-statistics-for-a-collection)

Comment: `
{"doCompact":true,"isVolatile":false,"journalSize":33554432,"indexBuckets":1,"count":683735,"figures":{"alive":{"count":683735,"size":263925640},"dead":{"count":54279,"size":18527000,"deletion":834811},"datafiles":{"count":87,"fileSize":5075981304},"journals":{"count":1,"fileSize":33554432},"compactors":{"count":0,"fileSize":0},"shapefiles":{"count":0,"fileSize":0},"shapes":{"count":15939858,"size":4769768800},"attributes":{"count":127,"size":6096},"indexes":{"count":3,"size":90564488},"lastTick":"32922777524129","uncollectedLogfileEntries":0},"status":3,"type":2,"error":false,"code":200}
`

Comment: I was getting connection reset because I had removed 8529 and was using only ssl. When I added 8529 I added it with ssl. My bad. fixed that and the output is as above. How do I get rid of shapes size. It seems it keeps the shapes for deleted data too.

Comment: Currently shapes aren't reference counted, and therefore no measure when to reclaim the space exists. The only available workaround would be to use an AQL query to copy the contents of that one collection into another one, then drop the first and rename (slower alternative: dump & restore). We're currently working on the internal storage engine, and expect that to be ready in Q1 2016. One of the side effects will be that this problem will be solved.

Comment: @dothebart is there any update on shapes optimization in newer version.

Comment: ArangoDB 3 has velocypack as dataformat - thus the concept of  shapes was removed.  Therefore datafiles can be dropped when all referenced documents are removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @dothebart suggested, It was due to the shapes size and currently it can be solved only by copying content of the collection to new collection and then delete old one and then rename the new collection with same name.